# XAML Error for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, compiler-errors

I'm trying to build my project and I keep getting these error messages:

`Error  1   The type 'System.Windows.Markup.IQueryAmbient' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. C:\Users\Geoff\Git\My Shopping List\My Shopping List\RunWindowItemList.xaml.cs  24  26  My Shopping List`

`Error  2   The type name 'IComponentConnector' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Windows.Markup'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.    C:\Users\Geoff\Git\My Shopping List\My Shopping List\obj\Debug\RunWindowItemList.g.cs   40  91  My Shopping List`

I tried looking up on MSDN how to remedy the situation, but I haven't found anything.  If anyone can help me with a solution or an article that has the solution, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Something that always works for me in vs 2012 is to terminate the designer process, XDecProc.. Hopes its still helpful in 2013

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check version of System.Xaml.dll used in your project and compare to .net version of this project. Seems you use old version System.Xaml.dll. You can find other dll in folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework

Comment: @GeoffOverfield, I had this problem after changing .net version 4->4.5.2 in my projects. Also check property "Copy local" for referenced library. First time I had no succes. Old library was placed in project's folder and VS could not add needed dll.

Comment: I was missing the `.XAML` assembly.  Didn't even know how to add it.  My buddy at work showed me.  #NoobStatus

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and after adding  `System.Xaml.dll` to my References the problem resolved!